# Search columns in Python Dataframe for account number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python Dataframe (df1) that looks like this:

```
    Stack name      Product Owner           Dev            Int             Preprod         Prod
0   aws-team-01     user1@company.com       052218651      324852125       456981984       321984984
1   aws-team-02     user2@company.com       268749013      257478547       946316984       151518919
2   aws-team-03     user3@company.com       544510823      158765489       546184089       846519849
3   aws-team-04     user4@company.com       298798651      698514785       984098499       441898156
4   aws-team-05     user5@company.com       874236874      349247469       015215289       741098709
```

I need to find a specific account number in one of the columns (Dev, Int, Preprod, Prod), and then get the Product Owner associated with that account number.

I can use something like this to get the row that contains the account number, but only if I know the column that contains the value. But I don't know which column will contain the value upfront, so this doesn't work in an automated way. The account numbers are unique and are not duplicated in any rows or columns

```
acctNum = 324852125
row = df1[df1['Int'] == acctNum]
```

If the acctNum is not in the column selected, I get the following error:
 `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`
Assuming I select the correct row that contains the acctNum, I can use the following to get the Product Owner (PO):

```
PO = row.iloc[0]['Product Owner']
```

This all works great, I just need to be able to search across the 4 possible columns that may contain the acctNum.

```
print(PO)
user1@company.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search through entire data frame by comparing against the value (not necessarily column by column):

```
cols = ['Dev', 'Int', 'Preprod', 'Prod']
df['Product Owner'][df[cols].eq(acctNum).any(1)]

#0    user1@company.com
#Name: Product Owner, dtype: object
```

`df[cols].eq(acctNum).any(1)` returns True for rows that contains the account number:

```
df[cols].eq(acctNum).any(1)

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

To get the first product owner:

```
pos = df['Product Owner'][df[cols].eq(acctNum).any(1)]
pos.iat[0] if len(pos) > 0 else None

# 'user1@company.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
acc = 324852125
look_in = ['Dev', 'Int', 'Preprod', 'Prod']
owner = list(df.loc[df[look_in].apply(lambda x: any(x == acc), axis=1), 'Product Owner'])[0]
print(owner)
>> user1@company.com
```

Comment: I get the following error when using this code. ```raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0```. If I remove the [0] from the end of the line , I get the following: ```28    user1@company.com
Name: Product Owner, dtype: object```